# How much force is required to push the CPU tab back down?

Tags: cpu, computer-building

I'm building my PC, and I am installing the CPU right now. I have all the sides flush, and the triangle is in the bottom left corner like it says, but I am having a little bit of trouble getting the containing handle thing back down... it's possible that I am afraid to apply too much force, or maybe I'm doing it wrong. Any experience? thanks!

Comment: It requires some force, but it shouldn't feel like you're breaking the handle. Are you sure the pins of the CPU are in the right holes and not shifted one row? For more specific instructions, you'd need to mention the motherboard / socket model I suppose...

Comment: well I lined it up, and made sure it was correctly fitted, and then went for it. It goraned a bit on the way down, but nothing snapped, and it locked in, so I think it's ok! we'll see once I try to run things haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check that the CPU is level with the bottom of the socket and feels like it's sitting properly. Then, apply the lever. Sometimes it will take quite a bit of force until you get past a certain point and then there's very little down the rest of the way until the lever is locked down.